# How to create MongoDB Time Series Collection using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

The [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/timeseries-collections/) shows how to do it with `mongosh`, but how do you create `Time Series Collection` using `pymongo` from within a python script?

```
import pymongo
import time
from datetime import datetime

client = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = client['time-series-db']
col = db['time-series-col']

# ... do something here to make it 'time-series collection' ...

js = {
    "1": "A",
    "2": "B",
    "3": "C",
    "4": "D",
    "5": "E",
}

# create BSON type datetime object needed for 'time-series collection'
ts = time.time()
js['timestamp'] = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts)

col.insert_one(js)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try this:

```
conn = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost')
db = conn.testDB

db.create_collection('testColl', timeseries={ 'timeField': 'timestamp' })
# - OR -
db.command('create', 'testColl', timeseries={ 'timeField': 'timestamp', 'metaField': 'data', 'granularity': 'hours' })
```

General Reference: [Time Series Collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/timeseries-collections/)

Comment: with `db.command` I'm actually getting the error: `raise OperationFailure(errmsg, code, response, max_wire_version)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: The field 'timeseries' is not a valid collection option. Options: { timeseries: { timeField: "timestamp", metaField: "data" } }, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'The field \'timeseries\' is not a valid collection option. Options: { timeseries: { timeField: "timestamp", metaField: "data" } }', 'code': 72, 'codeName': 'InvalidOptions'}`

Comment: You need to post a new question with details like MongoDB version, if you are using a PyMongo driver and Python versions. In case of any specific tools are used, mention them too. Also, include the exact code you are trying in your post (Please don't post detailed error messages in comments). @roschach

Answer (score 0):

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
db = client["database_name"]
collection = db["collection_name"]
collection.create_index({"time": pymongo.ASCENDING}, name="timeIndex")
collection.update_one(
    {"_id": 0},
    {"$set": {"timeseries": {"timeField": "time", "metaField": ["meta1", "meta2", "meta3"]}}},
    upsert=True,
)
```

if you are reading from pd/csv, and time is stored in your timezone like 02-02-2024 15:15:00 in "time" field, you can do

```
TIMEZONE_OFFSET = '+05:30'
original_time = datetime.strptime(row["time"], "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
row["time"] = original_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f") + TIMEZONE_OFFSET
```